# apt-get dependency issues

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

Getting a bit of trouble from apt-get, if I try to install anything I get.

```
apt-get install libcgi-session-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-0ubuntu13.1) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
 libkrb5-3 : Recommends: krb5-locales but it is not installable
             Breaks: libsmbclient (<= 2:3.6.1-2) but 2:3.5.8~dfsg-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
 libnih1 : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I follow that advice it tries to remove most of the install.

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjaxp1.3-java libreoffice-l10n-common ttf-dejavu-extra libpthread-stubs0 libqt4-network libqt4-dbus java-common dbconfig-common php5-gd x11proto-kb-dev libmysqlclient16 x11proto-input-dev libqtcore4 libgif4
  tzdata-java libvncserver0 daemon libxau-dev libqt4-xml wwwconfig-common postgresql-client-common php5-mysql libxcb1-dev mysql-common libnss3-1d x11proto-core-dev libmng1 libxdmcp-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient16 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libsdl1.2debian-alsa mysql-common php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
  php-pear php5-suhosin
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  acpi-support acpid aisleriot alsa-base alsa-utils anacron ant ant-optional apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-common apparmor apparmor-utils appmenu-qt apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl at at-spi
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils bamfdaemon banshee banshee-extension-soundmenu banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore baobab bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer brasero brltty brltty-x11 bsd-mailx
  build-essential ca-certificates-java capplets-data checkbox checkbox-gtk compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-main compizconfig-backend-gconf computer-janitor computer-janitor-gtk
  console-setup consolekit cron cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-driver-gutenprint cups-ppdc dbus dbus-x11 default-jre default-jre-headless dkms dmsetup drupal6 e2fsprogs eject empathy eog evince evolution
  evolution-data-server evolution-exchange evolution-indicator evolution-plugins evolution-webcal file-roller firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support foo2zjs friendly-recovery ftp g++ g++-4.5 gbrainy
  gconf-defaults-service gconf-editor gconf2 gconf2-common gdm gdm-guest-session gedit geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x ginn gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-3.0 gksu
  gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-bluetooth gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-media-common gnome-nettool gnome-orca gnome-panel
  gnome-panel-bonobo gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-system-tools gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine gparted grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc gs-cjk-resource
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-fuse gwibber hostname hplip hplip-cups ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx
  ifupdown indicator-applet indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-complete indicator-applet-session indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-me indicator-session indicator-sound initramfs-tools
  initscripts irqbalance jenkins jockey-common jockey-gtk kbd keyboard-configuration language-selector-gnome lftp libaccess-bridge-java libaccess-bridge-java-jni libapache2-mod-php5 libasound2-plugins libaudio2
  libbamf0 libbonoboui2-0 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcamel1.2-19 libcanberra-pulse libcompizconfig0 libcryptui0 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libebackend1.2-0 libebook1.2-10 libecal1.2-8 libedata-book1.2-8 libedata-cal1.2-10 libedataserver1.2-14 libedataserverui1.2-11 libegroupwise1.2-13
  libemail-valid-perl libevdocument3 libevolution libevview3 libgail-gnome-module libgconf2-4 libgconf2.0-cil libgdu0 libgksu2-0 libgnome-desktop-2-17 libgnome-media0 libgnome-vfs2.0-cil
  libgnome-window-settings1 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common libgnome2.24-cil libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd4 libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgs9 libgstfarsight0.10-0 libgtkhtml-editor0
  libgtkhtml3.14-19 libgweather-common libgweather1 libice-dev libice6 liblvm2app2.2 libmetacity-private0 libnet-dbus-perl libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnss-mdns liboobs-1-5 libpanel-applet-3-0 libpanel-applet2-0
  libparse-debcontrol-perl libparted0debian1 libpolkit-gtk-1-0 libpq5 libpulse-browse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpurple0 libqt4-opengl libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
  libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-writer librpc-xml-perl libsane libsane-hpaio libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsm-dev libsm6 libsmbclient libspectre1
  libstartup-notification0 libstdc++6-4.5-dev libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtelepathy-farsight0 libubuntuone-1.0-1 libubuntuone1.0-cil libunique-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwnck22 libwww-perl libx11-dev libxaw7
  libxerces2-java libxklavier16 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxmu6 libxres1 libxss1 libxt-dev libxt6 libxtst6 libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1 light-themes lintian linux-generic
  linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic linux-image-generic linux-sound-base logrotate media-player-info metacity metacity-common module-init-tools mountall mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto-empathy
  nautilus-share netbase network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd ntfs-3g ntpdate onboard openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openssh-server parted pcmciautils
  php5-pgsql pitivi plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pm-utils pnm2ppa policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome postfix postgresql postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4
  postgresql-common powermgmt-base ppp pppconfig pppoeconf pptp-linux procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils pxljr
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon-gtk python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-cups python-farsight python-gconf python-gnome2 python-papyon python-pyatspi python-smbc python-speechd
  python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-uno python-virtkey python-webkit python-wnck rsyslog samba-common-bin sane-utils screensaver-default-images seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell simple-scan smbclient
  software-center software-properties-gtk speech-dispatcher splix ssh system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev system-tools-backends telepathy-butterfly telepathy-haze
  telepathy-salut telnet tomboy totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-gtk tsclient ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-standard
  ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk udev udisks ufw unity unity-place-applications update-manager
  update-notifier upower upstart ureadahead usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data util-linux vim-gnome vinagre vino virtualbox-ose virtualbox-ose-dkms virtualbox-ose-qt
  wireless-crda x-ttcidfont-conf x11-apps x11-common x11-session-utils x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-mathml xfonts-scalable xfonts-utils xinit xorg
  xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-apm xserver-xorg-video-ark xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-chips xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-i128 xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-rendition xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-s3virge xserver-xorg-video-savage xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
  xserver-xorg-video-sis xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-tseng xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xserver-xorg-video-voodoo xterm
  xtrans-dev xul-ext-ubufox yelp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsdl1.2debian-alsa php5-cgi
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient16 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-xml libqtcore4 mysql-common php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  e2fsprogs util-linux (due to e2fsprogs) hostname upstart (due to hostname)
10 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 497 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 14.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,500 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] 
Abort.
```

I have tried

```
apt-get update
apt-get clean
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and a few other things but am getting no luck. Any help or insight much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've either:

- Installed a PPA which has overwritten some standard Ubuntu packages, or
- Changed your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to a different version of Ubuntu than you originally intsalled.

In the first case, temporarily remove the PPA.

In the second case, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to reflect the actual version of Ubuntu that you intend to have installed (e.g. `lucid` or `precise` etc.).

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```